# MonoTouch/Xamarin Windows phone corporate app

Tags: deployment, xamarin.ios, windows-mobile, xamarin

I want to start developing/deploying applications for windows phone in Xamarin.

Is there some enteprise approach to deploy corporate applications or i have to use Microsoft's way with AET and Developer account.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Which platform do you need to support?  If it is just Windows Phone, then you do not need Xamarin.  The distribution method is controlled by each platform vendor - for Windows phone, you would use the AET method for Enterprise distribution.

Comment: Actually i need uniform deployment workflow for iOs, Andorid and widnows phone. Android and iOS are great, but WP8 is horrible complex. Certificate phone with AET, than deploy app without any message about installation state.